# Selenium will not open site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to have selenium open a website in Microsoft Edge, and it will not open.
The code I am using is

```
from selenium import webdriver

# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.ChromiumEdge()
# get goodle.com
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

It returns this error:

```
File "c:\Users\Henry\OneDrive\Desktop\Genetic programming\starthere.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.ChromiumEdge()
  File "C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.EDGE['browserName'], "ms",
  File "C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'msedgedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
```

I did add the Webdriver exe file to the path, but it still gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding it to the `PATH` try this way pointing directly to the executable:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

s = Service(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
```

Comment: Your answer is using Chrome, not Edge

Comment: Thanks @JeffC. I did notice it before. I've just edited the answer

Comment: `ChromiumEdge` is not valid any more for current Edge versions. You should probably look at the docs to clean all this up before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the absolute path to help it locate your driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
#If the first path does not work, try the following one.
driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\\path\\to\\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://google.com")
```